# Error running Android (written in Kotlin) project compiled with Gradle2.0.0-alpha plugin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, instant-run

When compiling the project with the new `gradle2.0.0-alpha` pluggin I'm getting.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path:
    DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.inoutdelivery.enfesta-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry about the issues you are having with InstantRun. There is already a bug file for this issue at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195044 please update it with your issues.
it would help tremendously if a reproducible test case could be provided.

Answer (score 22):

On a non-Kotlin Android project, I was running into this same problem.  I solved it by turning Instant Run off (**Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run**), running my app, and then turning Instant Run back on.

Instant Run isn't working for me as advertised, but this at least got the app to build on 2.0.0-alpha.

Comment: Are you using it witk Kotlin?

Comment: Should have specified - I am not, just a normal Java Android project that gave the same exception.