# Strange RuntimeException when running an android app on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtimeexception

I have recently made an Android application and released the debug version to some people for testing purposes. All seems fine except to a few devices the app could not be run. After investigation the following exception was occurring when opening the app:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ir.irancell.neshan, PID: 23340
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.irancell.neshan-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.irancell.neshan-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:516)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4722)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ir.irancell.neshan-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/ir.irancell.neshan-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:981)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4722) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:172) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1368) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Strangely when I connect those problemed devices to Android Studio and compile the app specifically for them the app runs just fine. But if I generate an APK file and install them separately some devices still have that problem.
Googling the issue, some say ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880943/error-running-android-written-in-kotlin-project-compiled-with-gradle2-0-0-alph)) that the culprit is the `Instant Run` feature but I don't think `Instant Run` is responsible when you use `Generate signed APK`. So what could be the problem?

Comment: I would also think of Instant Run as the main problem here. You probably shouldn’t distribute debug APKs. Or at least, disable Instant Run before generating the APK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it seems that `Instant Run` was the culprit here. So disabling it resolved the issue.