# What is error? and how to solve

Tags: android

> 08-20 18:42:28.284 8769-8769/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                                  Process: com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset, PID: 8769
>                                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:680)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6395)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1005)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:670)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6395) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1887) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
>                                                                                                   Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm) /data/app/com.wordpress.prathamesh99wordpress.www.wifiset-1/base.apk ()
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:295)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:80)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:59)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:279)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makePathElements(DexPathList.java:248)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:120)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:48)
>                                                                                                      at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:65)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:86)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:47)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:438)
>                                                                                                      at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:663)
>                                                                                                           ... 9 more
>                                                                                                   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>                                                                                                      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>                                                                                                           ... 12 more
>                                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available

Comment: When you get this error ? On debugging or exported apk file ?

Comment: please show this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967703/unable-to-instantiate-application-com-android-tools-fd-runtime-bootstrapapplicat

Comment: When i run it it crashes please tell me whats the problem

Comment: Solved it... setting and build execution off the instant run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Run off (Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run -> Enable Instant Run)
```

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195044
[Error running Android (written in Kotlin) project compiled with Gradle2.0.0-alpha plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880943/error-running-android-written-in-kotlin-project-compiled-with-gradle2-0-0-alph/33882419#33882419)

I think it's the same problem.